# Cannot filter And Or for multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Currently, I have a table (2 columns ColumnName, Value) with data like this:

```
ColumnName     Value
CustomerName   Facebook
CompanyName    Google
```

How can I write a query with And / Or condition to satisfy the request:

- With And: 
  CustomerName = 'YAHOO' And  CompanyName = 'Google' will return 0 records
- With Or:
  CustomerName = 'Facebook' Or CompanyName = 'Google' will return 2 records

I have no idea to begin.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: your question is not clear. what output you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can research *EAV data model* for reasons why this model may not scale well.

You can query like so:

```
declare @YourTable table (ColumnName varchar(100), Value varchar(100) primary key (ColumnName, Value));
insert into @YourTable
    select 'CustomerName', 'Facebook' union all
    select 'CompanyName', 'Google';



--with And...
select *
from    @YourTable 
where   (ColumnName = 'CustomerName' and Value = 'Yahoo') and
        (ColumnName = 'CompanyName' and Value = 'Google')

--with Or...
select *
from    @YourTable 
where   (ColumnName = 'CustomerName' and Value = 'Facebook') or
        (ColumnName = 'CompanyName' and Value = 'Google')
```